# How to join results of multiple tables in Spring JPA repository which has same column names

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

I'm new to Spring and I'm trying to create my first Spring project. I want to create the query to get appointment data with `firstName` and `lastName` of a patient as well as `firstName` and `lastName` of the optometrist.
The problem is that the fields `firstName` and `lastName` are named the same for both patient and optometrist as they are fields from `AppUser`.
[Here is the database tables relationship diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRz7O.png)

There `@OneToOne` relationships between `AppUser` and `Patient` and between `AppUser` and `Optometrist`. There are `@OneToMany` relationships between `Patient` and `Appointment` and `Optometrist` and `Appointment`.

My DTO that I want  to retrieve:

```java
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public class AppointmentPatientOptometrist {
        private String patientFirstName;
        private String patientLastName;
        private String optometristFirstName;
        private String optometristLastName;
        private String status;
    }
```

My AppointmentsRepository with the query I tried to create (I tried to use "as" in the query to solve a problem of the same names):

```java
    public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment,Long> {
    
      @Query(value="SELECT new com.mypackage.dto.AppointmentPatientOptometrist"+
                "(up.firstName as patientFirstName, up.lastName as patientLastName, uo.firstName as optometristFirstName, " +
                "uo.lastName as optometristLastName, a.status)" +
                " FROM Appointment a  join a.patient p join a.optometrist o join o.appUser uo join p.appUser up")
        Page<AppointmentPatientOptometrist> loadAppointments(Pageable pageable);
    
    }
```

I would be grateful for any tips.

Comment: And what doesn't work. YOu don't need the aliasses.

Comment: Your code seems correct. `up.firstName` would get the `firstName` of the patient and `uo.firstName` would get the `firstName` of the optometrist. As far as I can see, it would work correctly. What is the result you are getting?

Comment: The error I'm getting is: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.mypackage.dao.AppointmentRepository.loadAppointments(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!

Comment: @M. Deinum, you're right. Aliases are not needed. Only order of arguments matters.  However, I still have problem with query validation  `@Query(value="SELECT new com.mypackage.dto.AppointmentPatientOptometrist (up.firstName,up.lastName,uo.firstName, uo.lastName,a.status) 
 FROM Appointment a  join a.patient p join a.optometrist o join o.appUser uo join p.appUser up")`

Comment: An error with query validation? What error message are you getting?

Comment: Try to look at the full stack trace, including the "Caused by" parts; it should give you a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: If you get an error please add it... If it is a stacktrace please add the **full stacktrace**.

Comment: Thank you, the cause of the problem was that I've implemented the status in Appointment class as Enum AppointmentStatus. The query was returning AppoitmentStatus type for status, not String as I thought. I've changed type of the status field from String to AppointmentStatus  in my DTO AppointmentPatientOptometrist  class and now it works fine. Thank you all  for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. The Query above is fine. The cause of the problem was that I've implemented the status in the `Appointment` class as `Enum` `AppointmentStatus`. The query was returning `AppoitmentStatus` type for `status`, not `String` as I thought. I've changed the type of the `status` field from `String` to `AppointmentStatus` in my DTO `AppointmentPatientOptometrist` class and now it works fine.  Thank you all for helping